# How to center the text and increase text size on bar chart using AchartEngine?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am able to implement bar chart, but there are various issues that I would like to correct it..

```
1 - How to center the text on bar?

2 - How to increase the text size on bar?

3 - can we change the orientation of bars?

4 - How to change colour of each bar?
```

Please Help guys.

Comment: @Dan can you help in my problem? I have seen you have solved all the questions related to achartengine.

Answer (score 3):

1. `renderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Align.CENTER);`
2. `renderer.setChartValuesTextSize();`
3. `renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);` but please note that this kind of chart is an experimental one.
4. Put them in separate series.

Comment: is renderer a XYSeriesRenderer?? If yes then I tried, but it doesn't make it center as well as don't increase size..

Comment: You probably didn't try the right thing. See this: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/TemperatureChart.java

Comment: setChartValuesTextSize() this function is deprecated is there any substitute of this function in chart library????

Comment: XYSeriesRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize() is not deprecated.

Comment: yes XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize() is  deprecated but you are right thanks it works now.

Comment: I want to change the text size of integer percentages inside pie chart

Comment: how to set the text size?